# How to get value from pluck laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, binding, eloquent

i want to take 2 value from pluck `id` and `nama_kelas`.

here my controller

```
$list_kelas = Kelas::pluck('nama_kelas', 'id');
      return view('siswa.create', compact('list_kelas'));
```

and my html

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="id_kelas" id="id_kelas">
    @foreach ($list_kelas as $kelas)
     <option value="">{{ $kelas }}</option>
    @endforeach
     </select>
```

i want to show `nama_kelas` in option and `id` in value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 @foreach ($list_kelas as $id => $kelas)
    <option value="{{$id}}">{{ $kelas }}</option>
 @endforeach
```